# Can't get any SharePoint services thru PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm trying to grab the Distributed Cache service using PowerShell so I can change the managed account that runs it. This cannot be changed through the CA UI.

I am not able to get the service using any of the following PowerShell commands (they return a null object).

`$farm` is set using `$farm = get-spfarm`

```
$farm.services | where ($_.TypeName -eq "Distributed Cache")

$farm.services | where ($_.Id -eq "<The GUID of the distributed cache service>")

$farm.services | where ($_.TypeName -match "Distributed"

$farm.services | where ($_.TypeName -like "*Distributed*")
```

I am running PowerShell as a local administrator and as the farm administrator. Again, all of these lines return  a null object. AFAIK any of these should get me the cache service. I can see it listed when I just enter `$farm.services` but somehow the pipe-filtering (?) is not working properly.

I'm not able to get any of the other services using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, the service called App fabric.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$cacheService = $farm.Services | where {$_.Name -eq "AppFabricCachingService"}
$accnt = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity domain_name\user_name
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.ManagedAccount = $accnt
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.Update() 
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.Deploy()
```

MSFT Official Article on this.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx#changesvcacct

Comment: I SWEAR I was using that EXACT script earlier! Strangely it worked though. Thanks.

Comment: dont worry, i have magic...:) glad its fixed.